# Django Postgres client on Azure

Tags: python, django, postgresql, azure

I am trying to get a Django app running on Azure and I would like to use a Postgres database that we already have in place.  So I need to have the psycopg2 python package installed.

Note: I am on a Mac and deploying with git.

My requirements.txt is simple:

```
django==1.6.2
pytz
psycopg2
```

However it fails when it gets to psycopyg2 while trying to find postgres binaries.

```
remote: Downloading/unpacking psycopg2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:   Running setup.py (path:D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\build\psycopg2\setup.py) egg_info for package psycopg2
remote:
remote:     Error: pg_config executable not found.
remote:
remote:     Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
remote:     or specify the full executable path with the option:
remote:
remote:         python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
remote:
remote:     or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
remote:     Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
remote:     running egg_info
remote:
remote: creating pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info
remote:
remote: writing pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\PKG-INFO
remote:
remote: writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\top_level.txt
remote:
remote: writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
remote:
remote: writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\psycopg2.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
remote:
remote: warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found
remote:
remote:
remote:
remote: Error: pg_config executable not found.
remote:
remote:
remote:
remote: Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
remote:
remote: or specify the full executable path with the option:
remote:
remote:
remote:
remote:     python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
remote:
remote:
remote:
remote: or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
```

I have tried adding the Windows Postgres binaries to my project at /pgsql and then updating the configurations in Azure to include that folder. I was hoping to be able to append to PATH, but the configure tab is telling me that is not allowed.

Seems like I might need a startup script or some other way to get these dependencies loaded. I couldn't find too many references on how to do this from a Mac, only Visual Studio.

Do I just need to move to a VM?

Comment: Here is psycopg for Windows. http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/ . Also windows Azure provides Linux machines whre you should not have such issues.

Comment: Yea, how do I get win-psycopg installed? I have been looking into updating the deployment.sh file to do it. Ideally, I don't want to use a VM.

Comment: @dds1024: did you amend your requirements.txt to do this in the end? I'm struggling with a similar problem.

Comment: Can't remember now. I tried seemingly everything and support was no help.  I was going to just move to VM's but decided to just stay on AWS. Sorry I can't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [psycopg2-windows](https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows).
Example for Python 2.7:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/nwcell/psycopg2-windows.git@win32-py27#egg=psycopg2
```

Also there are instruction for installation on [win-psycopg](http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/) ptoject home page.